# Is it possible to give action name same as controller name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my code.

When I give URL (/home/home) in browser but the styles and scripts not apply for this page.
Why i had this problem?

Comment: It should be another problem, this code is completely normal.

Comment: If the page loads then your controller/action are working fine. If there was a problem there the page wouldn't load at all. it's as dereli says, your problem is elsewhere. Use your browser tools to see what css / scripts the page is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

To display your css properly use the code below within  tags found in layout or master page (Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml for Razor)

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/styles/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```